# Изменение title в ToolBar вне OnCreate

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toolbar

Задумка такова, что при пролистывании viewpager'ом, будет меняться заголовок в ToolBar. То есть все вписано должно быть в обработчике перелистывания viewpager. Но изменить заголовок у меня получается только лишь внутри OnCreate

```
setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar_Main))
toolbar_Main.title = "Заголовок"
```

В выносных функциях toolbar_Main просто не виден, поэтому невозможно реализовать подобным кодом идею.

Как это возможно обойти? Заранее спасибо. Код на Java тоже пойдет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Делаем интерфейс:

   ```
   interface DataUpdater {
   fun update(title:String,subtitle:String)
   }
   ```

и используя его мы сможем из фрагмента передать данные в родительскую активность. Подключаем в активности:

```
class HomeScreen : AppCompatActivity(), DataUpdater{
...

override fun update(title: String, subtitle: String) {
      // сетим заголовок 
}
...
}
```

подключаем к фрагменту:

```
class SomeClass: Fragment(){
lateinit var updateUI: DataUpdater
...
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        if (context is DataUpdater) {
            updateUI = context
        }
}

}
```

и все.

2. Второй вариант:

   ```
   (activity as YourActivity).supportActionBar?.title = getString(R.string.your_title)
   ```

Так же есть подобные вопросы [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27100007/set-title-intoolbar-from-fragment-in-android), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917577/toolbar-title-in-fragments) и [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53354693/change-toolbar-title-when-fragment-changes).